# How to implement Access / Refresh Tokens

Tags: go, jwt, middleware, go-gin, paseto

I have been reading up about multiple ways one can implement refresh/access token logic. I've received mixed answers on how to tackle it. My API currently requires username/password authentication Where a short life PASETO token is issued, then verified via middleware per each request.

**Here is my current middleware** :

```
    const (
      authorizationHeaderKey  = "Authorization"
      authorizationTypeBearer = "bearer"
      authorizationPayloadKey = "authorization_payload"
    )

    func authMiddleWare(token tkn.Maker) gin.HandlerFunc {
        return func(c *gin.Context) {
    
            // Get the Value of the header
            authorizationHeader := c.GetHeader(authorizationHeaderKey)
    
            //Check if a value was provided
            if len(authorizationHeader) == 0 {
                err := errors.New("authorization header is not provided")
                c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
                return
            }
    
            // Split the Header string using space delimiter (separate 'Bearer' from <token>)
            fields := strings.Fields(authorizationHeader)
    
            if len(fields) < 2 {
                err := errors.New("invalid authorization header format")
                c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
                return
            }
    
            // Check the Authorization type of the token (first portion of token)
            authorizationType := strings.ToLower(fields[0])
    
            // Check if the auth type matches type bearer
            if authorizationType != authorizationTypeBearer {
                err := fmt.Errorf("unsupported authorization type %s", authorizationType)
                c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
                return
            }
    
            accessToken := fields[1]
    
            // Tell our token maker to verify the token
            payload, err := token.VerifyToken(accessToken)
    
            if err != nil {
                if errors.Is(err, tkn.ErrExpiredToken) {
                    // if refresh token is valid and not expired, create a new access token
                    // else return 403 and force user to re authenticate
                }
                c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
                return
            }
    
            // Set the payload in the context so the next handler can access it
            c.Set(authorizationPayloadKey, payload)
            c.Next()
    
        }
    
    }
```

**This is the implementation I am evaluating** (after updating my login endpoint to return 2 tokens, one for the access and one for the refresh) :

```
const (
    authorizationHeaderKey   = "Authorization"
    refreshHeaderKey         = "X-Refresh-Token"
    authorizationTypeBearer  = "Bearer"
    authorizationPayloadKey  = "authorization_payload"
)

func authMiddleWare(tokenMaker tkn.Maker) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {

        // Get the Value of the header
        authorizationHeader := c.GetHeader(authorizationHeaderKey)
        refreshTokenHeader := c.GetHeader(refreshHeaderKey)

        //Check if a value was provided
        if len(authorizationHeader) == 0 {
            err := errors.New("authorization header is not provided")
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
            return
        }

        // Split the Header string using space delimiter (separate 'Bearer' from <token>)
        fields := strings.Fields(authorizationHeader)

        if len(fields) < 2 {
            err := errors.New("invalid authorization header format")
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
            return
        }

        // Check the Authorization type of the token (first portion of token)
        authorizationType := strings.ToLower(fields[0])

        // Check if the auth type matches type bearer
        if authorizationType != strings.ToLower(authorizationTypeBearer) {
            err := fmt.Errorf("unsupported authorization type %s", authorizationType)
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
            return
        }

        accessToken := fields[1]

        // Tell our token maker to verify the token
        payload, err := tokenMaker.VerifyToken(accessToken)

        if err != nil {
            if errors.Is(err, tkn.ErrExpiredToken) {
                // if access token is expired, try to refresh it using the refresh token
                payload, err = tokenMaker.RefreshToken(refreshTokenHeader)
                if err != nil {
                    // if refresh token is invalid or not provided, return unauthorized status
                    c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
                    return
                }
                
                // generate a new access token
                newAccessToken, err := tokenMaker.CreateToken(payload.Username, addSomeDurationToCurrentTime())
                if err != nil {
                    c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
                    return
                }

                // replace the old access token with the new one
                accessToken = newAccessToken

                // optionally, set the new token in the response header
                c.Header(authorizationHeaderKey, fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", authorizationTypeBearer, newAccessToken))
            } else {
                c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
                return
            }
        }

        // Set the payload in the context so the next handler can access it
        c.Set(authorizationPayloadKey, payload)
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track or does my flow impose security risks ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this change? `tokenMaker.RefreshToken` might be performing some checks (e.g. has the token been revoked, has user access changed etc) but this is unclear. Sending both tokens with every request seems a little unusual (generally the refresh token would only be sent to an auth server) and you may want to consider preventing reuse of the refresh token. Note the warning in the [PASETO spec](https://github.com/paseto-standard/paseto-spec) "Caution: Neither JWT nor Paseto were designed for stateless session management.".